# How to lock two entire Hazelcast maps?

Tags: java, transactions, locking, hazelcast, isolation-level

I have two hazelcast `IMap`s. I need to do something similar to a full-join SQL query on their values.

Hazelcast `IMap.lock` locks only on one key, and Hazelcast transactions guarantee `REPEATABLE_READ` isolation at best.

How can I lock the two maps simultaneously so that the contents of one of them does not change while retrieving contents of the other one?

Answer (score 0):

Since Hazelcast is a NoSQL store it's not that feasible to run join queries on it and it's not supported too. Hazelcast already has [queries](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10/manual/html-single/#distributed-query) and [indexing](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10/manual/html-single/#indexing-queries), but for your use case maybe you can take a different approach here.

One approach would be to [co-locate your related data](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10/manual/html-single/#data-affinity) in the same partition and sending an [EntryProcessor](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10/manual/html-single/#entry-processor) to that partition to fetch all related data in a local operation with minimum network calls.